# Check if numeric type is subset of another

Tags: c++, templates, predicate, numeric-limits

I try to implement a meta function which checks if an integer type is a subset of another integer type. It should be platform independent and work at least with all numeric types defined by the C++ Standard. My current implementation has 5 branches. I have two questions about it.

1. Do I miss any cases?
2. Is the 4th branch necessary?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr bool is_subset(T1, T2)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T1, T2>)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T1, std::uintmax_t>)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T1, std::intmax_t>)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_unsigned_v<T1> && std::is_unsigned_v<T2>)
    {
        return static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T1>::min()) >= static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T2>::min()) &&
               static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T1>::max()) <= static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T2>::max())
    }
    else
    {
        return static_cast<std::intmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T1>::min()) >= static_cast<std::intmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T2>::min()) &&
               static_cast<std::intmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T1>::max()) <= static_cast<std::intmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T2>::max())
    }
}
```

Fixed implementation for intmax_t == long:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr bool is_subset2(T1, T2) noexcept
{
    if constexpr (sizeof(T1) == sizeof(T2) && std::is_signed_v<T1> == std::is_signed_v<T2>)
    {
        return true;
    }      
    else if constexpr (sizeof(T1) == sizeof(std::intmax_t))
    {
        return false;
    }   
    else if constexpr (std::is_unsigned_v<T1> && std::is_unsigned_v<T2>)
    {
        return static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T1>::min()) >= static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T2>::min()) &&
               static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T1>::max()) <= static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T2>::max());
    }
    else
    {
        return static_cast<std::intmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T1>::min()) >= static_cast<std::intmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T2>::min()) &&
               static_cast<std::intmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T1>::max()) <= static_cast<std::intmax_t>(std::numeric_limits<T2>::max());
    }
}
```

Comment: Only integers, including chars. All values of T1 must be valid values T2.

Comment: Fails for `is_subset<long, long long>(0L, 0LL)` on the many platforms where `std::numeric_limits<long>::max() == std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()`, and `std::is_same_v<long, std::intmax_t>`.

Comment: I see. Isn't that a bug? Is this true for newer compilers?

Comment: No, many 64 bit architectures do this. [Example for the common x86-64](https://godbolt.org/z/ka713A)

Comment: Added a fixed version.

Comment: None of the `if`s need to be the `constexpr` variety.

Comment: `if constexpr (sizeof(T1) == sizeof(std::intmax_t)) { return false; }` then all the types that are as wide as `intmax_t` will never be a subset of themselves?

Comment: "None of the ifs need to be the constexpr variety". But it is more efficient. Isn't it?

Comment: "if constexpr (sizeof(T1) == sizeof(std::intmax_t)) { return false; } then all the types that are as wide as intmax_t will never be a subset of themselves?" I think the first branch should handle these cases.

Comment: @MartinFehrs please tag people using `@` so they receive a notification. And your current implementation works correctly just because you're lucky. If the 2 types have different signness and different sizes then it'll jump to the last case. There if the unsigned type is `uintmax_t` then it'll be cast to `intmax_t` which results in the wrong min and max limits

Comment: @phuclv you're correct. I missed that case. My implementation is wrong. But currently I'm more interested in your solution anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have separate cases for `std::uintmax_t` and `std::intmax_t`. I think it can be simplified to only 3 cases:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr bool is_subset2(T1, T2) noexcept
{
    if constexpr (sizeof(T1) == sizeof(T2))
    {
        // true if both signed or both unsigned
        return std::is_signed_v<T1> == std::is_signed_v<T2>;
    }
    else if constexpr (sizeof(T1) < sizeof(T2))
    {
        // true if both unsigned, or T2 is signed
        return std::is_signed_v<T2> || std::is_unsigned_v<T1>;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks correct and is simpler then mine. I will mark this as an answer in a view hours. Maybe someone can find a case where it isn't working properly.